# Parsing string in json to java.time.LocalTime using json4s

Tags: json, scala, java-time, json4s

How can I parse a string of `YYYY-MM-dd` to `java.time.LocalDate`? Currently I have tried the following approaches:

1. import `JavaTimeSerializers`

> throws Error JString cannot be converted to LocalDate

```
case class Dates(createdAt: LocalDate, updatedAt: LocalDate, startDate: LocalDate, endDate: LocalDate )
implicit val formats =  defaultFormats ++ org.json4s.ext.JavaTimeSerializers.all

implicit val formats =  defaultFormats ++ org.json4s.ext.JavaTimeSerializers.all

val input =
  """
    |{
    |  "createdAt": "1999-12-10",
    |  "updatedAt": "1999-12-16",
    |  "startDate": "2000-01-02",
    |  "endDate": "200-01-16"
    |}
  """.stripMargin

val result = read[Dates] { input }
```

2. override `DefaultFormats`:

> throws error found java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter expected java.text.SimpleDateFormat

```
implicit val formats = new org.json4s.DefaultFormats {
  override def dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd")
}

val input =
  """
    |{
    |  "createdAt": "1999-12-10",
    |  "updatedAt": "1999-12-16",
    |  "startDate": "2000-01-02",
    |  "endDate": "200-01-16"
    |}
  """.stripMargin

val result = read[Dates] { input }
```

3. try to define `CustomFormatter` based on example here

> Error Expected type was: (PartialFunction[org.json4s.JValue,java.time.LocalDate], PartialFunction[Any,org.json4s.JValue])

```
object LocalDateSerializer extends CustomSerializer[LocalDate](
  format => (
{
  case JString(str) => LocalTime.parse(str)
  case JNull => null
}
))

implicit val formats =  org.json4s.DefaultFormats ++ new LocalDateSerializer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your third error, You are missing the second **Partial Function**, see:

```
ser: Formats => (PartialFunction[JValue, A], PartialFunction[Any, JValue])
```

so you maybe you want do it, like:

```
  object LocalDateSerializer extends CustomSerializer[LocalDate](format => ({
    case JString(str) =>
      LocalDate.parse(str)
  }, {
    case date: LocalDate => JString(date.toString)
  }))
```

and Since the `LocalDate` default pattern is `yyyy-MM-dd`, so `"200-01-16"` this is not a legal time, you maybe want to change it to `2000-01-16`.

Comment: thanks, the corrected code lives [here](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/scalaexercises/blob/master/src/test/scala/example/Json4sSpec.scala)